# Data Analysis and Poisson Error Propagation for a Dictionary of Numbers Using Matplotlib and Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dictionary that is created via `collections.defaultdict(list).` Each *key* in this dictionary is a real number in the range $(10^{8}, 10^{12})$ while it is associated with a `list` *value* having at most three elements. Here is an example:

```
dic={8.0056: [1, 1, 1], 8.0269: [1, 1], 8.0302: [2, 1, 2], 8.0426: [1], 8.0492: [1, 2, 1], 8.0766: [1, 1], 8.0817: [1], 8.1297: [1, 1, 1], 8.137: [4], 8.1778: [2, 2, 2], 8.1858: [2, 1, 2], 8.1948: [2, 2, 2], 8.2044: [1], 8.2143: [1], 8.3222: [4], 8.3314: [3], 8.3627: [1], 8.3818: [2], 8.436: [1, 1, 1], 8.4816: [3, 1], 8.4891: [3, 1, 1], 8.4932: [1], 8.5348: [3], 8.5924: [1], 8.6229: [1], 8.6698: [1, 3], 8.6826: [2], 8.7485: [1], 8.782: [1, 1, 2], 8.8158: [3], 8.8382: [2], 8.8708: [1], 8.8737: [1], 8.882: [2], 9.1274: [1, 1, 1], 9.3071: [1, 1, 1], 9.3373: [1, 1, 1], 9.3564: [1, 2, 1], 9.367: [5], 9.4711: [1, 1, 1], 9.5184: [3, 3, 6], 9.6954: [2, 2, 3], 9.7214: [1], 9.743: [1, 1, 1], 9.8061: [1], 9.9565: [1, 2], 10.0249: [2], 10.0734: [2, 2], 10.0917: [5, 1], 10.2095: [2, 4, 5], 10.2967: [2, 3, 1], 10.3707: [4, 1, 4], 10.8679: [9, 7, 9], 10.9173: [8, 17, 9], 8.0022: [1], 8.0504: [2], 8.0527: [1], 8.0645: [2], 8.1836: [2, 1], 8.2122: [1, 1], 8.2433: [1, 4], 8.2849: [1], 8.396: [3], 8.64: [3], 8.6793: [3], 8.8079: [2], 8.8313: [4], 8.8396: [1], 8.8666: [1], 9.0763: [1, 4], 9.2683: [1], 9.7969: [4, 5], 9.8302: [1, 1], 10.0856: [1], 10.2049: [4, 7], 10.7051: [3, 2], 8.0082: [1], 8.0245: [2], 8.1414: [1], 8.1661: [1], 8.2014: [1], 8.2794: [1], 8.3103: [2], 8.4627: [1], 8.5279: [2], 8.5326: [3], 8.5507: [1], 9.4476: [5]})
```

Now, I would like to plot two sets of figures. In both figures, x-axis corresponds to the `key`s of the mentioned dict above where they are binned into 11 bins according to the following assignment:

```
x_bins=np.logspace(8.20, 12.20, 11)
```

*These are the central points of the 11 bins *(8.00,8.40), (8.40,8.80),(8.80,9.20),...,(12.00,12.40)*

---

FIGURE1:

To plot first figure, my y_axis would be total *number* of `key`s in each bin such that each `key`'s contribution to that bin is weighted by the *number* of elements in the corresponding list. (If list has three elements, it will weigh 1 and if it has two elements, it will weigh *2/3* and if it has only one element, it will weigh only *1/3*)

*Here we don't care about the numerical values inside lists.

---

FIGURE2:

To plot second figure, my y-axis would be the `average` *value* of the elements of the list corresponding to each `key` (e.g. *1/3* of the sum of elements) adding up all these contributions from all other `key`s inside each bin. This plot needs to be normalized in the sense that sum of all heights at the center of all bins need to add up to unity.

---

These are all central values of y_axes. I also need to introduce Poisson error when plotting my errorbars for either one of two plots. In real life, lists should be infinitely large but we happen to have a very small statistics for each `key` of exactly three elements (even though zeros are missing). This is why I need Poisson instead of Gaussian statistics. In either one of `errorbar` plots, as you can see, there are two steps of introducing uncertainty for each bin; one coming from each individual `key` while the other coming from all the `key`s inside that bin.

---

Questions:

1. How to form central values for each bin?
2. How to form lower and upper uncertainty when adding two Poisson errors for each mass bin?

Here is my code to answer question 1 which doesn't seem to work:

```
from itertools import islice
import numpy as np
import ast
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

dic={8.0056: [1, 1, 1], 8.0269: [1, 1], 8.0302: [2, 1, 2], 8.0426: [1], 8.0492: [1, 2, 1], 8.0766: [1, 1], 8.0817: [1], 8.1297: [1, 1, 1], 8.137: [4], 8.1778: [2, 2, 2], 8.1858: [2, 1, 2], 8.1948: [2, 2, 2], 8.2044: [1], 8.2143: [1], 8.3222: [4], 8.3314: [3], 8.3627: [1], 8.3818: [2], 8.436: [1, 1, 1], 8.4816: [3, 1], 8.4891: [3, 1, 1], 8.4932: [1], 8.5348: [3], 8.5924: [1], 8.6229: [1], 8.6698: [1, 3], 8.6826: [2], 8.7485: [1], 8.782: [1, 1, 2], 8.8158: [3], 8.8382: [2], 8.8708: [1], 8.8737: [1], 8.882: [2], 9.1274: [1, 1, 1], 9.3071: [1, 1, 1], 9.3373: [1, 1, 1], 9.3564: [1, 2, 1], 9.367: [5], 9.4711: [1, 1, 1], 9.5184: [3, 3, 6], 9.6954: [2, 2, 3], 9.7214: [1], 9.743: [1, 1, 1], 9.8061: [1], 9.9565: [1, 2], 10.0249: [2], 10.0734: [2, 2], 10.0917: [5, 1], 10.2095: [2, 4, 5], 10.2967: [2, 3, 1], 10.3707: [4, 1, 4], 10.8679: [9, 7, 9], 10.9173: [8, 17, 9], 8.0022: [1], 8.0504: [2], 8.0527: [1], 8.0645: [2], 8.1836: [2, 1], 8.2122: [1, 1], 8.2433: [1, 4], 8.2849: [1], 8.396: [3], 8.64: [3], 8.6793: [3], 8.8079: [2], 8.8313: [4], 8.8396: [1], 8.8666: [1], 9.0763: [1, 4], 9.2683: [1], 9.7969: [4, 5], 9.8302: [1, 1], 10.0856: [1], 10.2049: [4, 7], 10.7051: [3, 2], 8.0082: [1], 8.0245: [2], 8.1414: [1], 8.1661: [1], 8.2014: [1], 8.2794: [1], 8.3103: [2], 8.4627: [1], 8.5279: [2], 8.5326: [3], 8.5507: [1], 9.4476: [5]})

plot1_dict, plot2_dict, dm = {}, {}, 0.4
for key in dic.keys():
    plot1_dict[key] = np.size(dic[key])/3
    plot2_dict[key] = np.sum(dic[key])/3
plot1_list, plot2_list = plot1_dict.items(), plot2_dict.items()

plot1_xbins, plot1_yvalues = list(zip(*plot1_list))[0], list(zip(*plot1_list))[1]
plot2_xbins, plot2_yvalues = list(zip(*plot2_list))[0], list(zip(*plot2_list))[1]

plot1_list, plot2_list = list(plot1_list), list(plot2_list)

plot1_y_values = []
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  0*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  1*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  1*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  2*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  2*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  3*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  3*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  4*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  4*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  5*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  5*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  6*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  6*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  7*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  7*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  8*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  8*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  9*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  9*dm <= item[0] <= 8. + 10*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. + 10*dm <= item[0] <= 8. + 11*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]

print(y_values)
```

Error Message:

```
File "my_code.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
    plot1_y_values  += [sum(item[1]) if (8. +  0*dm <= item[0] <= 8. +  1*dm) else 0 for item in plot1_list]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be clearly linked to one programming language and library. Please include this information in the question and tags (rather than using the rather generic tags list, dictionary and propagation).

Comment: thank you, I intended to do all this in python. Did you mean I need to put down "python" as one of the tags?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Also put the plotting library (if there is any) in the tags